# React JS and PHP contact form fails

Tags: php, reactjs, contact-form

I'm having an issue with my website. To give some context, I've worked on it using ReactJS for the front-end and Express for the back-end. BUT, my hosting provider doesn't support Node, so I had to change the back-end part to PHP. I only developed the contact form functionality.
I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but I would like to ask your opinion to continue due to I'm stuck.

Here's the front-end part for Contact.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';


class Contact extends Component{

    render(){
        return(

           <div>
    <form id="contact-form" name="c-form" method="post" action="/mailer.php">
                                        <div className="input-field">
                                            <input
                                                id="first_name"
                                                type="text"
                                                className="validate"
                                                name="first_name"
                                                required/>
                                            <label for="first_name">Name</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="input-field">
                                            <input id="sub" type="text" className="validate" name="sub"/>
                                            <label for="sub">Subject</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="input-field">
                                            <input id="email" type="email" className="validate" name="email" required/>
                                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="input-field">
                                            <textarea
                                                id="textarea1"
                                                className="materialize-textarea"
                                                name="message"
                                                required></textarea>
                                            <label for="textarea1">Message</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="contact-send">
                                            <button
                                                id="submit"
                                                name="contactSubmit"
                                                type="submit"
                                                value="Submit"
                                                className="btn waves-effect">Send
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>             
</div>

        )
    }
}

export default Contact;
```

and also, the back-end part in the PHP file, mailer.php located under /src folder:

```
<?php

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "*HERE I PLACED MY EMAIL*";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }

?>
```

The result is:

```
POST http://www.*mywebsite.com*/mailer.php 400 (Bad Request)
```

Any suggestion or recommendation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: check network request details - you probably make a request to your machine (localhost) and react's developing (node) server - it doesn't support php files... you have to use compiled react files uploaded to php server, the same where you have mailer.php ... it should work but it's a little react abusing - react should make an ajax call (send data to script using js, not using POST request and new route)

Answer (score 0):

change mailer.php

```
$name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
```

to

```
$name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["first_name"]));
```

Comment: Thanks! I did that and the new response from the action was: Proxy error: Could not proxy request /mailer.php from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001 (ECONNREFUSED). Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: well, vane. that's a different problem. you should mark my answer as correct for your main question, and then create a new question.

Comment: Ok Matteus, I will mark your answer as useful but as the main problem wasn't solved, I'll keep the ticket until I get more support to find out what's going on :) Thanks again!